# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled in react

Tags: reactjs

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

error
`Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled`

after I push the latest code in my GitHub account, then I try to install my GitHub code into another react application when I do npm start I`m facing this

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled